# How many five-card hands contain exactly one pair of the same rank and three other cards of different ranks?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, poker

How many five-card hands contain exactly one pair of the same rank and three other cards of different ranks?

This is my thought process:

I first multiply it by $13 \binom{4}{2}$, since there are $13$ possible rank pairs we can create and then multiply by $12\cdot11\cdot10$ for each different rank we choose. Meaning the total number of combinations is $$13 \cdot \dbinom{4}{2} \cdot 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10$$

Is this right?

Comment: No.  There are $\binom {12}3$ ways to choose three ranks other than the one that defines the pair.  Then there are $4^3$ ways to choose suits for those three ranks.

Comment: Note:  don't write things like $121110$ to denote $12\times 11\times 10$, it's confusing.

Comment: Use `$a \times b$` to denote $a \times b$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating the number of poker hands that have exactly 4 different denominations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696398/calculating-the-number-of-poker-hands-that-have-exactly-4-different-denomination)